# Issue with executing prepared statement in Node JS with ibm_db module

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, db2

I am new to NodeJS technology, while working on nodejs project, I got below issue.

I have implemented ibm_db module (to establish DB2 connection), and using "prepared statements" to execute 'SELECT' queries. Below query is executed without errors but `console.log(result)` is giving result as `{fetchMode : 4}`, but I am expecting COLUMN_1 results here. Can someone tell me if I am missing anything here.

```
db.prepare('SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_2=?', function(err, stmt){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        stmt.execute(['CA'], function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
        });
});
```

Comment: try logging the error here: May be there is some error?  `stmt.execute(['CA'], function(err, result){ console.log(err, result); });`

Comment: @SKY just now I checked that, there is no error occurred.

Comment: Am little new to DB2 and ibm_db module, what does fetchMode: 4 stand for?

Comment: Do you need to call this: `result.closeSync();`

Comment: @SKY I have no idea on fetchMode.

Comment: I think you should use `query()` for, well, queries; `execute()` is for DML statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an extra fetch inside of execute callback makes it possible for me to see the correct and wanted result of the query statement.
Here an example:

```
db.prepare('SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_2=?', function(err, stmt){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    stmt.execute(['CA'], function(err, result){
        result.fetch(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            result.closeSync();
        });
    });
});
```

The following site gave me the hint: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/node-ibm_db/AhZeeN6jFTM/MrRXSIW3DQAJ